# how can I vectorize an operation on a structure in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, data-structures, vectorization

I have a structure that has several fields each containing a vector of numbers that I want to take their average without a for looping each field ,

```
a.a=[1 2 3 4 5]
a.b=[4 5 6 7 8 9];
a.c=[23 23 3 3 ];
...
```

how can I vectorize that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `structfun` for that, for example:

```
result = structfun(@mean,a)
```